# ListView 'New' Button Override using Aura - Not working while clicking for the second time

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to override the "New" button in the ListView using Aura and LWC.
Here's my requirement: When user clicks "New," I want to present different UIs for record creation based on the user's location. If the user location is Turkey, I want to display an LWC within an Aura component. Otherwise, I'm using Lightning Navigation to navigate to the record creation page.
The functionality works well on the initial click of the "New" button. However, if the user opens the new record page and then closes it, clicking "New" again doesn't load the component.

Aura Component

```
    <aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride,lightning:hasPageReference"
                controller="CustomValidationController">
    <aura:attribute name="isTurkeyUser" type="boolean" default="false"/>  
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRecordTypeId" type="Id"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="objectApiName" type="string"/>  
    <aura:attribute name="pageReference" type="Object"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/> 
    <lightning:listView aura:id="listView"
        objectApiName="{!v.objectApiName}"
        listName="Recent"
        rows="15"
        showActionBar="true"
        showRowLevelActions="true"
        enableInlineEdit="true"/>
    
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isTurkeyUser}">  
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <lightning:buttonIcon 
                        iconName="utility:close"
                        onclick="{!c.closeModal}"
                        alternativeText="close"
                        class="slds-modal__close"
                    />
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <c:lwcOverrideNewProject 
                        selectedRecordTypeId ="{!v.selectedRecordTypeId}"
                        objectApiName = "{!v.objectApiName}">
                    </c:lwcOverrideNewProject>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Aura Controller

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) 
    { 
        //component.set("v.isModalOpen", true);
        
        component.set("v.isTurkeyUser", false);
        console.log('isTurkeyUser >> ' + component.get("v.isTurkeyUser"));

        //Get RecordTypeId
        var recordTypeId = component.get("v.pageReference").state.recordTypeId;
        component.set("v.selectedRecordTypeId", recordTypeId);
        console.log('recordTypeId >> ' + recordTypeId);

        //Get Object API Name
        var objectApiName = component.get("v.pageReference").attributes.objectApiName;
        component.set("v.objectApiName", objectApiName);
        console.log('objectApiName >> ' + objectApiName);

        //Get current UserId
        var userId = $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id");
        console.log('userId >> ' + userId);

        //Get User Location
        var action = component.get("c.getUserLocation");
        action.setParams({ userId : userId })
        action.setCallback(this, function(response)
        {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state == 'SUCCESS') 
            {
                if(response.getReturnValue() === 'TRY')
                {
                    component.set("v.isTurkeyUser", true);                   
                }
                else
                {
                    component.set("v.isTurkeyUser", false);
                    
                    var pageReference = {
                        type: 'standard__objectPage',
                        attributes: {
                            objectApiName: component.get("v.objectApiName"),
                            actionName: 'new'
                        },
                        state: {
                            nooverride: '1',
                            recordTypeId: component.get("v.selectedRecordTypeId"),
                            layoutType: 'Full'
                        }
                    };
                    component.find("navService").navigate(pageReference);
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },   

    //Close Modal
    closeModal : function(component, event, helper) 
    {
        component.set("v.isTurkeyUser", false);

        var navService = component.find("navService");
        var pageReference = 
        {
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Project__c',
                actionName: 'list'
            },
            state: {
                filterName: "Recent"
            }
        };

        component.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);
        
        navService.navigate(pageReference);

        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire()
    }
})
```

LWC Component

```
<template>
        <lightning-card>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <lightning-input label="Project Headline" value onblur={handleInputBlur}></lightning-input>
                <template if:true={matchingRecords.length}>
                    <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                        <p class="slds-text-color_error">Records with similar Project Headline already exist in the system.</p>
                        <div class="slds-m-top_medium" style="max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;"> 
                            <lightning-datatable
                                key-field="id"
                                data={matchingRecords}
                                columns={columnList}
                                hide-checkbox-column="true"
                            ></lightning-datatable>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </template>
                <div class="slds-m-top_medium" >
                    <lightning-button label="Create Project" onclick={createProject} variant="brand"></lightning-button>     
                </div>
            </div>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

LWC Controller

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation'
import { encodeDefaultFieldValues } from 'lightning/pageReferenceUtils'
import getCurrentUserId from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import findSimilarRecords  from '@salesforce/apex/CustomValidationController.fetchLookupData';

const columns = 
[
    {label:"Name", fieldName : "projectUrl", type: "url",
     typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: "projectName" }, target: "_blank",
     cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' }, initialWidth: 'auto'}
    },
    { label: 'Similarity Score', fieldName: 'levenshteinDistance', type: 'number',
      cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' }, initialWidth: 150 }
];

export default class LwcOverrideNewProject extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement)
{
    @api selectedRecordTypeId;
    @api objectApiName; 
    userId = getCurrentUserId; 
    userLocation = '';
    isRenderTemplate = false;
    matchingRecords = [];
    columnList = columns;
    projectHeadline = '';


    handleInputBlur(event) 
    {
        const inputValue = event.target.value;
        this.findSimilarRecords(inputValue);
        this.projectHeadline = inputValue;
    }

    connectedCallback()
    {

    }

    findSimilarRecords(inputValue) 
    {
        findSimilarRecords({ searchKey: inputValue })
            .then(result => 
            {
                this.matchingRecords = result.map(record => ({
                    id: record.project.Id,
                    projectName: record.project.Project_Headline__c,
                    levenshteinDistance: record.levenshteinDistance,
                    projectUrl: 'https://orgbaseUrl.sandbox.lightning.force.com/' + record.project.Id
                }));
                console.log(this.matchingRecords);
            })
            .catch(error => 
            {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    createProject() 
    { 
        this.navigateToNewRecordPage();    
    }

    navigateToNewRecordPage()
    {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](
        {
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: 
            {
                objectApiName: this.objectApiName,
                actionName: 'new'
            },
            state: 
            {
                nooverride: '1',
                recordTypeId: this.selectedRecordTypeId,
                layoutType: 'Full',
                defaultFieldValues:
                encodeDefaultFieldValues({
                Project_Headline__c: this.projectHeadline
                })
            }
        });
    }
}
```